# I created the registration form localhost ta but it does not work on the real site

Tags: php

I created a registration form on localhost and this form works on localhost and is fast. Am using php 5.6 on localhost and my site.  but my site is running very slowly (.html pages are running pretty fast) and does not send the registration form information. I google it and found nothin.
Sorry for the mistakes I might have made.

```
<?PHP
require ('config/config.inc.php');

if(isset($_POST['register'])) { 

    if(empty($_POST['benutzername']) && empty($_POST['passwort']) && empty($_POST['email']) && empty($_POST['lieblingsfarbe'])) {
        echo '<p>Tüm Alanların Doldurulması Zorunludur!</p>';
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/^a-zA-Z0-9@-._ÖöÄäÜü/', $_POST['benutzername']) && preg_match('/^a-zA-Z0-9@-._ÖöÄäÜü/', $_POST['passwort']) &&
            preg_match('/^a-zA-Z0-9@-._ÖöÄäÜü/', $_POST['email']) && preg_match('/^a-zA-Z0-9@-._ÖöÄäÜü/', $_POST['lieblingsfarbe'])) {
        echo '<p>Es ist nur: a-Z,0-9,@,.,_,- erlaubt!</p>';
    }
    else {
        $benutzername = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['benutzername']);
        $passwort = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['passwort']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
        $antwort = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lieblingsfarbe']);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO account.account
            (login, password, social_id, email, create_time, question1, answer1, status, safebox_expire, autoloot_expire, coins)
            VALUES
            ('" . $benutzername . "', PASSWORD('" . $passwort . "'), '" . $loeschcode . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $zeit . "', '" . $frage . "',
            '" . $antwort . "', '" . $status . "', '" . $date . "', '" . $date . "', '" . $registercoins . "')";
    $qry = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if($qry) {
        echo '<p id="nachricht" style="color:green;">ßaşarıyla Hesap Oluşturdunuz!</p>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<p id="nachricht" style="color:red;">Kayıt Başarısız!</p>';

    }
}
    <head>
        <title><?PHP echo $servername ?></title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/design.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
<body>

    <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="box">
        <form action="index.php" method="post" id="login">
            <center>
                <p>Kulanıcı Adı</p>
                <input type="text" name="benutzername" maxlength="16" />

                <p>Şifre</p>
                <input type="password" name="passwort" maxlength="16" />

                <p>E-Posta</p>
                <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="20" />

                <p>En Sevdiğiniz Renk ?</p>
                <input type="text" name="lieblingsfarbe" maxlength="8" />

                <input type="submit" name="register" value="" />
            </center>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>© Copyright by <?PHP echo $servername ?>. All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think `^a-zA-Z0-9@-._ÖöÄäÜü` is what you want. I think you want a character class there. Also the `-` needs to be at the start or end. You also shouldn't use the mysql `PASSWORD` function anymore. Use PHPs password_hash and password_verify. Also you'd be better off parameterizing your query.

Comment: You also should use `or`s for the `empty` conditionals. Currently that requests that all fields are not empty, I'd think you want the logic to be any of the fields. You also should `exit` or `die` there, as is your insert will still fire. For your actual issue you asked about though you're going to need to explain further. It doesn't work or it is slow? If slow where is the bottleneck?

Comment: it working quite fast and %100 working on localhost. when i upload my form to my site, its became very slow and doens't send info to database.

Comment: It doesn't send or it doesn't insert? Check your error logs and access logs. The only way this could/should work (as currently written) is if all fields have `a-zA-Z0-9@-*_ÖöÄäÜü` submitted as their input (with the exception of the `*` which could be any non new line character because it is a `.` in your regex.